# Anylogic: Behavioural Experiment using Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, systemdynamics

I would like to do an online experiment with human participants backed up by simulation. In the experiment, participants need to change the parameters and run simulations based on their changed parameters. Their changes need to be saved for data analysis.

I wonder if it is feasible to do this using anyLogic or anyLogic cloud. The essential features are:

1. The model needs to be shared with participants; ideally, they do not have to download anyLogic to complete the experiment.
2. The changes that participants made need to be saved and downloaded.

Have anyone had the experience of doing similar things?

Many thanks,

I reached out to the salespeople of AnyLogic. They believed that this is feasible but hadn't seen anyone had done this before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this... but in order to do this, you need either the anylogic professional version or the anylogic cloud subscription, or the AnyLogic private cloud (best option)

This is not possible using PLE/public cloud, because to do this you need to either be able to export the executable file (which requires professional version) and/or you need to export the data to a centralized database (which requires the anylogic cloud subscription as a minimum to have access to this feature)

**Option with Professional version using exported executable**

- You export your model and send to all of them a link to download it
- You use a centralized database to save every action the user makes to it
  Con of this option: i would say 30% of the users will have issues with their JAVA version, computer issues, and other issues and you will have to do troubleshooting with them on an individual basis. If you have 1000 users, then this will be virtually impossible to manage

**Option with AnyLogic cloud subscription**

- You export your model to AnyLogic cloud
- you use a centralized database (using Zapier or your own SQL database) that will save the data every time a user changes anything

Con of this option: you will need all users to have a cloud subscription, OR you will need all users to use the same user/password to have access to the model. I am not sure with 1000 users what would happen if you have so many people using the same user/password.. According to AnyLogic, what they told me is that there's no limitation there.

**Option with AnyLogic Private Cloud**
With this option you have absolute freedom to do what you want. I haven't done it here, but it's also the most expensive option.